# Can flip effects be in response to something?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I cast a spell that would destroy my opponent's face down creature, and in response she flipped it to trigger its flip effect. Can she do that? I thought you could only do that as a Flip Summon during your Main Phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, she cannot.

Monsters are only flipped face up under certain conditions:

1. Flip summon - a flip summon during the main phase, like you describe in your question.
2. Damage step - During the battle phase when a face down defense position monster is attacked.
3. Resolving an effect - When an effect specifically instructs to flip a monster face up, or instructs you to change a face down monster into attack position, which requires the monster become face up.

Answer (score 2):

> Can she do that?

As per your description, No.

The reason is that probably **the card you used to destroy that face down monster, does the destruction without flipping the monster**, contrary to, say, attacking the monster (where it then would indeed flip).

Therefore, no flip effect is activated, as the card didn't actually flip.

As we can see from the Flip effect [ruling](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Flip_effect), this only activates if the monster is flipped (by attack, summon or other effect):

> This kind of effect activates when the Flip monster is flipped face-up (by battle, a Flip Summon, or a card effect).

Comment: Sure, I was targeting her 4-Starred Ladybug of Doom with my Shield Crush. We weren't sure if cards that said `FLIP: [Do something.]` could be flipped at any time, like an activated ability in MTG (if you know MTG). Our Mtg knowledge is both helping and hurting us with Yu gi oh, lol. Reworded, I wasn't sure if the `FLIP: [Do something.]` was basically just a triggered ability attached to its flip summon, or if it was an option to flip at other times.

Comment: @Aerovistae with those cards then my answer holds. Shield Crush destroys the Ladybug without flipping it. "Flip" effects *only* activate when the card is flipped (either with a Flip Summon, being attacked before damage calculation, or well some card effect that flips face up). In other words, it does not activate that "ability" as it does not meet the criteria needed for it to activate (that is, to be flipped). enhancing answer

Comment: @Aerovistae - I see the confustion, MTG writes activated effects like that, in this case this is the equivalent of a triggered effect in MTG, where flip is the trigger.

Comment: @Aerovistae yup, as Andrew said, that would be the equivalence. Furthermore, the "activated" abilities here in YGO *could* be similar to what is known as Continuous Effects, which most of the time don't need a trigger or cause for it to activate, as they are constantly active when face up on the field or when another condition is met for that specific effect.

Comment: I do like this game quite a lot, but god damn they are not good at wording the rules text on the cards. Also @DarkCygnus I think the continuous effects would best be likened to MTG's static abilities, which likewise are always in effect and require no active choice from the player in order to take effect once on the field.

Comment: @Aerovistae interesting, probably doing MTG-YGO equivalences is not a great idea haha, but does help to understand better. And yeah, seems that Konami preferred to give more detail to the rulebook and less to the cards, assuming the player knows a great deal of the Rulebook (instead of being more explicit on the cards)... But :) its part of learning I guess. I must suggest you try to keep those MTG analogies to a minimum, as they may confuse you more than they can help I think. Cheers